QGIS and MapInfo projections - EPSG3301 (Estonian Coordinate system/projection: L-EST97 1 mm)
I have MapInfo .tab file with points. Tab file is created with MapInfo Pro version 2023 (release build 142). The .tab file's coordinate system (projection) is Estonian coordinate system. In MapInfo it's name is "L-EST97 1 mm tapsus EUREF89" and it's description in MapInfo MAPINFOW.PRJ file is: "L-EST97 1 mm tapsus (EUREF89)\p3301", 2003, 115, 7, 24, 57.51755393056, 58, 59.33333333, 500000, 6375000, -503054.52549999999, 5371945.4740000004, 1503054.5260000001, 7378054.5259999996". It is official Estonian coordinate system (projection) and it should be same as ESPG3301. MapInfo default "Table projection" and "Session projection" options in my MapInfo are using the same L-EST97 projection. The points in this .tab in MapInfo look like in below figure.

Now I make a copy of that .tab file in MapInfo (Save Copy As) and open the copy in QGIS (version: 3.28.13-Firenze, more detailed version info in figure below).
QGIS has default coordinate CRS "EPSG: 3301 - Estonian Coordinate System of 1997" (figure below).
Now I export this layer in QGIS to MapInfo .tab (Export--> Save Features As)(figure below).. File name "Points_from_QGIS_LEST.
Exported layer was added to QGIS (symbol: black stars) and there can be seen a visual shift (figure below).
Now I open the exported .tab file (Points_from_QGIS_LEST) in MapInfo and the shift is seen here too. Also MapInfo does not recognize the projection although it should be "L-EST97 1 mm tapsus EUREF89" or EPSG3301 (figure below). 
Now I save a copy from "Points_from_QGIS_LEST" in MapInfo to assign it a MapInfo LEST projection. File name "Points_from_QGIS_LEST_copy". In figure below the shift in zoomed in MapInfo map window is shown. Distance between original points (red star) and points from QGIS (black star, file name "Points_from_QGIS_LEST_copy") is 7,64 mm. Centroid coordinates of that point  calculated in MapInfo with CentroidX(obj) and CentroidY(obj) functions are 512316,97319204 and 6565773,8371214 (original point); 512316,98021342 and 6565773,8401306 (point from "Points_from_QGIS_LEST_copy").

The same shift occurs with other geometry types, for example with polylines. There is MapInfo and  .tab based work environment in my institution, but QGIS has some useful tools, I would like to use them, but this undesired shift is changing data. Are projection descriptions different in QGIS (GDAL?) and MapInfo? Can this "shift" problem in QGIS be fixed somehow?

Hi there, I don’t have a copy of map info so sorry if I make stupid suggestions. Could you try creating a similar file in mapinfo with the same projection, in MIF format? Then do the same export steps in qgis. If you open the ‘.mif’ files in notepad, near the top should be a line that describes the Projection - compare that line between the mapinfo exported file and the who’s exported file.

Sorry autocorrect changed “qgis exported file” to “who’s exported file”

Thanks for your suggestion. I came up with the idea to try it myself already. I wrote it to QGIS here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/58283. Projection from mid/mif saved from MapInfo is:

"CoordSys Earth Projection 3, 115, "m", 24, 57.51755393056, 58, 59.33333333, 500000, 6375000 Bounds (-503054.5255, 5371945.474) (1503054.526, 7378054.526)." Projection from mid/mif from QGIS is: "CoordSys Earth Projection 3, 104, "m", 24, 57.5175539305556, 59.3333333333333, 58, 500000, 6375000". When I substitute projection in notepad in mif from QGIS with projection from MapInfo mif the gap in MapInfo is gone. So I guess the missing "Bounds" part in QGIS mif is causing it.

In a Mapinfo MAP file, coordinates are stored as an integer value. Atom (minimal) step of coordinates is equal to 1/2e+09 of the difference between the X( or Y) boundaries.
Thus, if the program has changed/lost boundaries, saving the data using the “Save As (to another projection definition)” command or receiving data from GDAL/OGR without defining “BOUNDS=”,
you will get a small uneven shift in the coordinates of the points.
For 1 mm accuracy you are to correct MAPINFOW.PRJ file in Mapinfo folder so that BOUNDS difference is equal to 2000 km or 1000 km or 500 km or 400 km or 200 km or 100 km.
Original MAPINFOW.PRJ often has BOUNDS in meters recalculated from inches. So it has very strange values of BOUNDS and as well original coordinates in Mapinfo Table are not rounded to 1 mm or 1 cm.
